# How to scaling svg text based on it's container?

Tags: svg

I have circle that contain text inside. The problem is the number so dynamic between 1 to thousand, I need to make it keep inside the circle like using viewbox but for text inside circle

This is the print screen
[image]

How to make it inside the circle??

Comment: Not sure it's possible without using script. Here's my failed attempt at a solution without script: http://jsfiddle.net/V9xw2/.

Comment: @ErikDahlström if using script, what are going to do with the text?

Comment: That depends on how you want it to behave, do you want it to stay a circle when the text length increases, or e.g use a rounded rect with the same radius instead? A script could call `yourtext.getBBox()` and then adjust the circle radius as needed.